# set a class on a div with ng-class on pageload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As in the title, I'm trying to set a class on a div on page load ( not on a click ) with angular `ng-class` but I have no clue how to or if it is possible. The `div` is wrapped in a module and controller where I was previously trying to set the variable with `$scope.frontpage` but it didn't work.

```
<div id="main" role="main" class="clearfix" data-ng-module="ValidationBoxModule" ng-controller="ValidationBoxClassController">
    <div validation-id="dataValidationSummary" validation-summary ng-class="frontpage" ></div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

angular.module("ValidationBoxModule", []).controller("ValidationBoxClassController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.frontpage = "";

    ($("#main").find(".sliderBox")) ? $scope.frontpage = "frontpage" : $scope.frontpage = "";
}]);
```

So is there a way to do it ?

Comment: how do you identify that div?

Comment: jQuery is also loaded, yes

Comment: If you wired everything correctly, there is no need to do stuff *on pageload*. See: http://jsbin.com/unihon/2/ So you might want to add enough code so that we can reproduce your problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not *the angular way*. As in: "don't do DOM manipulation in the controller". Instead use a directive, e.g:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.frontpage = false;
}

angular.module('app', ['app.directives']);

angular.module('app.directives', []).directive('isFrontpage', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.frontpage = angular.element(element).find('#main .sliderBox').length > 0;
    }
  };
});
```

with:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl" is-frontpage>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="sliderBox"></div>
  </div>

  <div
    validation-id="dataValidationSummary"
    validation-summary
    ng-class="{frontpage: frontpage}">
  </div>
</body>
```

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/unihon/4/

Comment: It works in the demo, maybe you can work out the differences to your actual code.

Comment: I see that it does, it must be something in my code ... it's a big project and it isn't easy to find stuff ...

Comment: It often issn't ;)  Hopefully the example is enough to get you on the right track!

Comment: seems like the controller works, and if I console something, I see it in the console, but the directive might not be working ....